# What results can I expect from a quantized Tensoflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tpu

I have a very simple Tensorflow model that outputs 3 value (left, straight, right) based in the input from 6 sensors (input range from 0.0 to 1.0)

```
inputSensor = Input(shape=(3))
modelSensor = Dense(32, activation="relu")(inputSensor)
modelSensor = Dense(32, activation="relu")(modelSensor)
modelSensor = Dense(numClasses, activation="softmax")(modelSensor)
model = Model(inputs=inputSensor, outputs=modelSensor)
```

After training the model I can convert it into a normal TFLite model using

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("models/modelpath.h5")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
```

tflite_model = converter.convert()

Then I run some inference tests on the model I get the results that I expect. One of the 3 outsputs
is at 99%, the others very low.

TEST RIGHT
Input [0.0,0.0,1.0]
Result [[0.00089144 0.00154889 0.99755967]]

TEST Straight
Input [0.0,1.0,0.0]
Result [[0.00087439 0.996424   0.00270158]]

TEST LEFT
Input [1.0,0.0,0.0]
Result [[0.9948014  0.00256803 0.00263061]]

Then I quantize the model (in order to use it on a edge TPU)

```
converter =tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter. from_keras_model_file 
("models/modelpath.h5")
converter.representative_dataset = representativeDataset_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = 
[tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
```

and I run the same test as above. The results are still correct, but I get 132 on the max output and 62 on the others.

TEST RIGHT
Input [0.0,0.0,1.0]
[[ 62  62 132]]

TEST Straight
Input [0.0,1.0,0.0]
[[ 62 132  62]]

TEST LEFT
Input [1.0,0.0,0.0]
[[132  62  62]]

I would have expect to get a result in the range of [[255  0  0]]

The same thing happens, when I use integer inputs like
Input [0,0,255]

Is there something wrong with the quantazion conversion?
And should I use Integers of floats as input?

Answer (score 0):

Small sized models will certainly suffer from large accuracy drop when you do post-training quantization. In fact, it has been advised by TensorFlow Team to perform the accuracy check after post-training quantization has been applied.

In case the accuracy is suffering badly, it has been suggested to make use of [`quantization-aware-training`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#model_accuracy).

At the point of writing this answer, the quantization aware training is yet to be launched.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself.

The representative dataset that i was using for the quant-conversion was not representative enough. It consisted of an array of zero's. Using a proper dataset (the same one as used for training) fixed the outputs -> [[255   0   0]]